# Jquery i want Same effect again and again on every click

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i am appending my jquery code below.When i click on + link one text box should slidedown that is working Fine.But I want same effect when again and everytime click on +.Hope any one can help me

`Jquery`

```
$(".more_button").click(function(){
    $("#topping_more").slideDown();
    });
**Html Code**

<div class="display_none" id="topping_more">
  <p>
      <label></label>
       <input type="text" name="topping"  maxlength="50" class="validate[required]" value="<?php //echo set_value('topping',$this->form_data->topping);?>"/>
      <span><strong>price</strong></span>
       <input style="width:80px;" type="text" name="price"  maxlength="50" class="validate[required]" value="<?php //echo set_value('menu_item',$this->form_data->menu_item);?>"/>
  </p>
</div>
 <p>
     <a style="margin-left:650px;"  id="add_more" class="more_button fl"> + </a>
 </p>
```

i want same this kind of effect http://jsfiddle.net/7yU3n/ ...but when i click again on add same **Added** should be der under the previous **Added**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `clone()` to clone the input and `appendTo` to add it in a block

**HTML**

```
 <div id="displayblock"> //add this block in your html
    <div class="display_none" id="topping_more">
    ....
    </div>
 </div>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(".more_button").click(function(){
   $("#topping_more").clone().appendTo('#displayblock').slideDown();
});​
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yU3n/10/)

---

**UPDATED**

**JQUERY**

```
 var clickedcount = 1; 
 $(".more_button").click(function(){            
   $("#topping_more").clone().attr('id','topping_more'+clickedcount).appendTo('#displayblock');

   var newSpan = $('<span>',{
                 class:"close",
                 text:"close"

             });
   newSpan.appendTo($('#topping_more'+clickedcount).find('p'));
   $('#topping_more'+clickedcount).slideDown();
   clickedcount++;
 });

 $('#displayblock').on('click','.close',function(){
    $(this).parent().slideUp('slow',function(){
        $(this).parent().remove();
  });
});
```

new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7yU3n/14/) here

Comment: Hi @bipen ,Thanks for this help.I have used ur code now i want to add one <span>close</span> after the price and when i click on close every paryicular textboxes shold be closed any idea?

Comment: there u go... updated my answer.. check the new fiddle.... let me know if any problem...

Comment: Thanks exactly the same i wanted.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know wat exactly u want but this code is if you want to silde up and down on every click

```
$(".more_button").click(function(){

    if($("#topping_more").css('display')=='hide'){    
          $("#topping_more").slideDown();
    }else{
          $("#topping_more").slideUp();
}

    });
```

This code is for sliding every time down....

```
$(".more_button").click(function(){
$("#topping_more").slideUp();
$("#topping_more").slideDown();
});
```

Comment: Sorry bro!..This is not what i want. Iwant evry time slide down with the new topping more div under the previous one

Answer (score 1):

You can also clone the p tag and append it to div like below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".more_button").click(function(e)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#topping_more").slideDown();
            var clone = $("#topping_more p:first").clone();
            $("#topping_more").append(clone);

            //also do below
            var clone = $("#topping_more p:first").clone();
            clone.appendTo("#topping_more").slideDown('slow');
            //also above will work
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="display_none" id="topping_more" style="display:none;">
  <p>
      <label></label>
       <input type="text" name="topping"  maxlength="50" class="validate[required]" value="<?php //echo set_value('topping',$this->form_data->topping);?>"/>
      <span><strong>price</strong></span>
       <input style="width:80px;" type="text" name="price"  maxlength="50" class="validate[required]" value="<?php //echo set_value('menu_item',$this->form_data->menu_item);?>"/>
  </p>
</div>
<p>
    <a style="margin-left:650px;"  id="add_more" class="more_button fl" href="#"> ADD </a>
</p>
```

in response to your comment you can also give p tag style display none and appendTo div and slide it down then you will not see two p when first click.

Comment: thanks @Dipesh One issue is der first time i click on + button it slide down two <p> and then every time normal that is one...any idea

Comment: Hi Thanks for this help.i want to add one <span>close</span> after the price and when i click on close every particular textboxes shold be closed any idea?